# TCP/IP listener variable byte length

Tags: c#, tcp

I have a stream coming in that varies in length but has a start and stop character. When I run this code:

```
public TCPListener()
{
        Int32 port = 31001;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.78"); //Local
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        server.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            // Console.Write("Waiting for a connection...-- ");
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();

            // Console.WriteLine("new client connected");
            try
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(HandleClient), client);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
        }
    }

    private void HandleClient(object tcpClient)
    {
        // string path = @"c:\Test.txt";
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)tcpClient;
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[135];
        String data = null;
        int i;

        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                URLObject oU = new URLObject();
                oU = oDecode.TextFrameDecode(data);
                Console.WriteLine(data);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }

        // Console.WriteLine(data);
}
```

I get a lot of data every second; I get the data, but it's broken up sometimes into chunks that are not parsable. When I run this code to look for the end delimiter, the feed only get one connection every couple of minutes with only one record so I think the data is getting truncated which is not correct.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        Int32 port = 31001;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.78"); //Local
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        server.Start();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Waiting for a connection...-- ");
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("new client connected");

            try
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(HandleClient), client);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
        }
}

static void HandleClient(object tcpClient)
{
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)tcpClient;
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[135];
        String data = null;
        int i;

        try
        {
            using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string inputLine = reader.ReadLineSingleBreak();
                inputLine = inputLine + "#";
                Console.WriteLine(inputLine);
                URLObject oU = new URLObject();
                oU = oDecode.TextFrameDecode(inputLine);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
}

public static class StreamReaderExtensions
{
    public static string ReadLineSingleBreak(this StreamReader self)
    {
        StringBuilder currentLine = new StringBuilder();
        int i;
        char c;

        while ((i = self.Read()) >= 0)
        {
            c = (char)i;

            if (c == '#')
            {
                break;
            }

            currentLine.Append(c);
        }

        return currentLine.ToString();
    }
}
```

I need a mix of both... get all the data but then parse it correctly.

Comment: AFAIK you shouldn't assume that each `Read` call reads a full message. I'd start by modifying that `stream.Read` loop: append the results of each `Read` call to a buffer, and only parse that buffer when the latest `Read` call contained a stop character.

Comment: Your `HandleClient` method in the second example doesn't have a loop. It cannot process more than a single record, since it simply *ends* after the first one. The first example assumes that a single `Write` on the sending side causes a single `Read` on the receiving side - that simply isn't true for TCP. TCP is a stream-based protocol, it doesn't have "messages" - so read it as a stream. A single `Read` can receive less than one of your messages, or more of them at the same time. Be ready for that.

Comment: you can greatly simplify the implementation if instead of using delimiter you prepend your data by its size, of course if you can modify your protocol, e.g.  to send "some data" string you actually send "[9]some data" where `[9]` is 4 bytes int with value `9` in binary form

Comment: I do not have access to modify the data being sent, I just have to take what they give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did fix it by Pieter Witvoet advice:

```
static private TcpListener server = null;
    static private Decode oDecode = new Decode();
    static private string sLeftOver = string.Empty;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Int32 port = 31001;
        IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.78"); //Local
        server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
        server.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Waiting for a connection...-- ");
            TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("new client connected");
            try
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(HandleClient), client);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { }
        }
    }
    static void HandleClient(object tcpClient)
    {
        TcpClient client = (TcpClient)tcpClient;
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
        String data = null;
        int i;
        try
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
            {
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                URLObject oU = new URLObject();

                Console.WriteLine(data);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                //Split data here
                string[] aData = Regex.Split(data, @"(?<=[#])");
                foreach (string s in aData)
                {
                    string sData = s;
                    sData = sLeftOver + sData;
                    if (sData.EndsWith("#"))
                    {
                        sLeftOver = string.Empty;
                        Console.WriteLine(sData);
                        Console.WriteLine("");
                        oU = oDecode.TextFrameDecode(sData);
                                                }
                    else
                    {
                        sLeftOver = s;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { }
    }
```